# Installing SQL Server 2008 Express Edition with Fulltext Indexing

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

According to this page, SQL Server 2008 Express Edition with Advanced Services includes Fulltext search:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/

However, I downloaded it, ran it, and I see no sign of it.  There is no fulltext service, and when I try to do anything to do with fulltext it says

> Msg 7609, Level 17, State 5, Line 1
>   Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.

When I run the re-installer to add features, I still don't see it.  It claims I have everything installed.

Any ideas?

[image: sql_server_2008]

Comment: this is exactly the situation i am experiencing. Seans answer is absolutely correct. It was driving me nuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the screenshot, you downloaded the "Runtime with Management Tools" instead of "Runtime with Advanced Services" which includes Fulltext and Reporting Services.  The x64 installer for SQL Server 2008 Express Edition with Advanced Services is here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/9/b/e9bcf5d7-2421-464f-94dc-0c694ba1b5a4/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe

Comment: In my case, what actually happened is that I was running the correct installer, but during setup I had chosen an existing instance of SQL Server that was already running with the less-capable version.  The advanced services installer won't let you *add those features* to an existing install.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks we cannot add fulltext search service to basic Express edition. When you start new installation (not update of Express edition) there will be this option aviable.

I had to reinstall SQL Server to this extended edition.